# What to do when I receive a contract from a company I have to reply to the same day?

Tags: job-offer, negotiation, contracts, contract-extension

I was working at a startup company for a year making less than minimum wage. Eventually it got to the point where I could not continue and got a very lucrative job making about 20k more a year than is normal for my experience. Though it was only a 2 month contract.

During this contract I was contacted by a new company (the dream job) but only to be hired as an intern. The job was offering 30k less a year than the current job I had. My contract was coming to an end. They sent me the contract when I was at work. I looked at the contract later that night and noticed that I had to reply by midnight the same day. It was too late at night to contact anyone about the contract. I had no choice but to accept or miss the date.

Now I am at this new job on a 3 month contract. Making about 10k less than someone of my experience should be making. They are offering to hire me full time and are preparing another letter. I need this job and can't really afford to turn it down. Though I would be kind of bitter to be making such a low wage.

**I am worried that once again the contract must be responded to within the same day I receive it, leaving no room to negotiate.**

So my question is basically, how bad is it to miss the deadline stated on the contract? Is it likely I will lose the job? Also if they do reject my offer is the old offer off the table? Did I just turn the job away?

To put this into perspective, this is one of the biggest companies (if not the biggest) in my profession. I beat out a lot of people to get this job and it's basically my dream job. They have more than enough money to pay me though the reviews of the company say salaries are a little low at this place. I am fairly new to the concept of yearly wages versus an hourly rate. Or when it is appropriate to ask for more money.

Comment: Accept not except.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> They sent me the contract when I was at work. I looked at the contract later that night and noticed that I had to reply by midnight the same day.

This is a huge red flag to me. There's no legitimate reason to be pushing a contract so abruptly unless you're betting that the receiving party doesn't have immediate access to an attorney.

I'm going to be blunt about this. You've got 2 options here:

- Ask for extra time to look at the contract. Sit down, read it, and bring up any concerns. If you would like to discuss **any** aspects, then discuss them.
- Accept the contract as-is, leaving you vulnerable to being screwed over.

I could **never** accept a contract until I have thoroughly read and understood it. If I have time to understand a contract, then I have time to negotiate a contract.

I would advise against accepting any contract until you have **understood** the contract. If you have any concerns, whether it be your hours/wage/etc, then bring it up. If they are willing to accept those terms, make sure to get a physical copy of the new contract before signing it. If they aren't willing to accept those terms, then you get to decided whether your "dream job" with this company is worth the terms or not.

> how bad is it to miss the deadline stated on the contract?

That depends on the language of the contract. Get a lawyer.

> Is it likely I will lose the job?

If your current contract is up, and you have no new contract, then you aren't legally working for them anymore.

> Also if they do reject my offer is the old offer off the table?

Your old offer is with the old contract. You can try to negotiate the new contract to be of similar terms of the old one, but that is up to the hiring company if they are willing to accept those terms.

> Did I just turn the job away?

Depends on what you have or have not done, you really haven't specified anything that would say "yes" or "no.

Comment: Thanks for the response, only one thing I was asking If they make me a offer on my new contract and then I say I would like at least x more dollars. They say no. Can I still accept the original offer that I asked for more on? Or is that offer no longer on the table?

Comment: @marsh that's entirely up to them.  However, the way these people are jerking you around, I wouldn't advise staying any longer than it takes to find an employer who isn't an idiot.

Comment: While I agree, I might tough it out to at least a year, just to get a reasonable amount of time with the biggest name in the industry onto my CV. Maybe accept this one, then see what is on offer next time? But, if so, start looking/familiarizing yourself with the market  a few months before pay rise time.